# Is a std::vector threadsafe if the threads read and write in disjoint index ranges?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdvector

Suppose, I have a `std::vector<int>` of length 4, which is constant. Then there are 4 threads, where thread `i` reads and writes only index `i`. Is this threadsafe? Can the single elements be changed independently of each other? I wonder because they are close so that they are probably loaded all at once into a cacheline.

Does it make a difference if the index range per thread is larger than 1?

EDIT:

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and hence C++03. Any hints about differences from C++03 to C++11 are welcome!

Comment: In practise, with your platform and compiler, this will work.  C++11 just *guaranteed* it will work.

Comment: It should work, but it might be unefficient for small ranges because of false sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's fine. Different threads can operate on different ranges of elements.

According to the `C++11` Standard:

> **23.2.2** Container data races **[container.requirements.dataraces]**
>
> **2** Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting vector<bool>, are modified concurrently.

**Edit:** Before `C++11` concurrency and data races are never mentioned, so the spec took no account of them and made no guarantees.